# Proving that $z^4-6z^2+4z-3 = y^2$ has only one integer solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof, square-numbers

I'm trying to prove the following result.

**Conjecture.** If $z$ is an integer, and $z^4-6z^2+4z-3$ is a square, then $z=3$.

A quick check modulo $9$ shows that $z=9w+3$ for some integer $w$. So for some integer $y$ we must have
\begin{align}
y^2 &= z^4-6z^2+4z-3  \\
  &= (9w+3)^4 - 6(9w+3)^2 + 4(9w+3) - 3\\
  &= 9(729w^4 + 972w^3 + 432w^2 + 76w + 4).
\end{align}
So $y = 3u$ for an integer $u$, and hence
$$
  u^2 = 729w^4 + 972w^3 + 432w^2 + 76w + 4.
$$

From here, I can rearrange and factor as
$$
  (u-2)(u+2) = w(729w^3 + 972w^2 + 432w + 76)
$$
then write
\begin{align}
  u-2 &= w_1r,  & w &= w_1w_2,  \\
  u+2 &= w_2s,  & 729w^3 + 972w^2 + 432w + 76 &= rs,
\end{align}
for integers $r,s,w_1,w_2$, and start slogging away from there. This method has worked well for me in the past, resulting in the discovery of elementary proofs of results which previously had only non-elementary proofs. But I feel like there must be a more elegant (but still elementary) method of attack from this point, so I'm looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless $|z|$ is very small, for $z >0,$ $z^4 - 6 z^2 + 4z - 3$ is larger than $(z^2 -3)^2$ but smaller than $(z^2 -2)^2.$ Since it is in between consecutive squares, it is not a square. For $z<0,$ it is between $(z^2 -4)^2$ and $(z^2 -3)^2.$

Comment: How small is "very small"? Is there a precise bound?

Comment: Never mind… I worked it out:
$$(z^4-6z^2+4z-3)-(z^2-3)^2 = 4z-12$$
and
$$(z^2-2)^2-(z^4-6z^2+4z-3) = 2z^2-4z+7$$.

Comment: See <http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1689425/93271> for the application. Thanks again!